# Find centroid of topoJSON path and use it to position a circle in D3

Tags: d3.js, topojson

In my data I have values associated with countries. I have created scaled circles for each country and would now like to position them at the centre of each country using cx and cy.

I have generated a map using topoJSON that has country-code 'ids' and I have matching country-codes in my data (cd).

```
{"type": "Polygon",
"id": 604,
"arcs": [
  [133, -473, -448, -378, -374, -413]
 ]
},
```

Using D3's [path.centroid(feature)](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#path_centroid), how can I find the centroid of each topoJSON path?

```
g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(cd)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "bubble")
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return r(+d.Value)
    })

g.selectAll("path")
  .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
    .geometries)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
```

Full code here [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/L0dyJboDsngOrJTe2ANh?p=info)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it would be like this:

```
  // bind the map data
  var paths = g.selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
      .geometries)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path);

  g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(cd)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "bubble")
    .attr("r", function(d){
      return r(+d.Value);
    })
    // using the map data
    // position a circle for matches in cd array
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      for (var i = 0; i < paths.data().length; i++){
        var p = paths.data()[i];
        if (p.id === d["country-code"]){
          var t = path.centroid(p);
          return "translate(" + t + ")";
        }
      }
    });
```

Updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8HnN6C7zpY4BzKrZrwGQ?p=preview)

**For Comments**

In the situation you describe, I always stash the x/y position in my data array:

```
g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(cd)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "bubble")
    .attr("r", function(d){
      return r(+d.Value);
    })
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      for (var i = 0; i < paths.data().length; i++){
        var p = paths.data()[i];
        if (p.id === d["country-code"]){
          var t = path.centroid(p);
          d.x = t[0];
          d.y = t[1];
          return d.x;
        }
      }
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d){
      return d.y;
    })
```

The objects in your `cd` array will now have additional properties of x/y pixel positions.

Updated [plunker two](https://plnkr.co/edit/SWgCaR3nlGHdpOXqo8ML?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, using translate works great! How can I do this using cx and cy positioning? (I'd like to use these dimensions to position my div tooltips and text labels also)

Answer (score 2):

I would compute the GeoJSON equivalent of the TopoJSON features, and use [`d3.geo.centroid`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#centroid) to calculate the geographic center of each feature. From an example I wrote some time ago (drawing each country as a square with proportional area, centered on each country’s centroid):

```
var geojson = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.countries).features;

// Compute the projected centroid, area and length of the side
// of the squares.
geojson.forEach(function(d) {
  d.centroid = projection(d3.geo.centroid(d));
  // more calculations...
});
```

The full example is available at http://bl.ocks.org/pnavarrc/14ed098d4072be2715db

Comment: Thanks for the example! Although I'm still having trouble converting to GeoJSON https://plnkr.co/edit/f5Ps9afPdqdSCk3zUoiv?p=info getting error that feature isn't a function. Am I referencing the wrong object? https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference